# Error message "Linter pylint is not installed"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want to run Python code in Microsoft Visual Studio Code but it gives an error:

> Linter pylint is not installed

I installed:

- The Visual Studio Code Python extension
- Python 3
- Anaconda

How can I install Pylint?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

1. Open a terminal (`ctrl+~`)
2. Run the command `pip install pylint`

**If that doesn't work:** On the off chance you've configured a non-default Python path for your editor, you'll need to match that Python's install location with the pip executable you're calling from the terminal.

This is an issue because the Python extension's [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) enable [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) by default. If you'd rather turn off linting, you can instead change this setting from `true` to `false` in your user or workspace settings:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
```

Comment: pip install pylint command gives this error
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: This is likely because pip isn't on your path, so you can't run it directly from the terminal. If python is on your path, you should be able to run `python -m pip install pylint`.

Comment: If Python isn't on your path, you may want to add it, so you can run Python from the command line in the future. Instructions for adding an executable to your path vary by platform, but should be easy to find.

Alternatively, you could just turn off linting, for now :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Thank You @Ben for solution

Comment: See @RutoCollins [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989777/3585557) for how to configure VS Code to use the pylint already installed (which is installed if, like the OP states, you installed Anaconda Python).  If you do not have desire/access to change you `PATH` variable, that is the best option.

Comment: The terminal (`Ctrl-\`` not `Ctrl-~`) uses the same Python environment as the actual shell and pylint is installed. VSCode is using something different and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 128):

Check the path Pylint has been installed to, by typing `which pylint` on  your terminal.

You will get something like: `/usr/local/bin/pylint`

Copy it.

Go to your Visual Studio Code settings in the `preferences` tab and find the line that goes

`"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint"`

Edit the line to be

`"python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint"`,

replacing the value `"pylint"` with the path you got from typing `which pylint`.

Save your changes and reload Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This would be a good approach if the installation happened already. In this case it seems that since pylint isn't there it's not the best approach.

Comment: @user2867432 The OP states that Anaconda Python is installed, which comes with `pylint` already installed.  The problem is that Anaconda Python is not automatically added to the path.  For those who do not have access/desire to change their path, this is absolutely the best approach.

Comment: VScode does weird stuff here. If I open a terminal inside my vscode project, inside the pipenv I'm using, i can type `flake8` or `pylint` or `which pylint` no problem. Still VSCode seems to require an explicit path. :/

Comment: The following worked for my Anaconda install on windows `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\pylint.exe`. Not too surprising, it did not work with forward slashes.

Comment: Fow windows users, ```which``` is linux command and you must use ```where```. Although for me ```where pylint``` did not help. Hence I just performed ```pip3 install pylint```, which told me the path by: 
```Requirement already satisfied: pylint in ``` 

```c:\users\keshavb\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2.4.2)```

Comment: Easier way, just can change the pyLintPath to ```C:\Users\_your_username_AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\pylint.exe```

Comment: This works, but I'd love to know why VSCode isn't using the same `python`, `pip`, and `pylint` that are in the `PATH` of the shell I started it from.

Answer (score 7):

If you're working in a virtual environment ([virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)), you'll definitely need to update the `python.lintint.pylintPath` setting (and probably the `python.pythonPath` setting, as well, if you haven't already) if you want linting to work, like this:

```
// File "settings.json" (workspace-specific one is probably best)
{
    // ...
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "C:/myproject/venv/Scripts/pylint.exe",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:/myproject/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
    // ...
}
```

That's for Windows, but other OSs are similar. The `.exe` extension was necessary for it to work for me on Windows, even though it's not required when actually running it in the console.

If you just want to disable it, then use the `python.linting.pylintEnabled": false` setting as mentioned in [Ben Delaney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272791/871990).

Comment: `pylint.exe` is needed in pylint installation folder. But the `.exe` is not in the `settings.json`. I.e.: `"python.linting.pylintPath": "C:/myproject/venv/Scripts/pylint"`

Answer (score 7):

This solved the issue for me:

```
pip install pylint -U
```

I.e., upgrade the `pylint` package.

Comment: My problem was that the message `Module pylinter not installed` would pop up constantly, but pylinter _was_ installed in both Python2 and Python3. Upgrading pylint from within the terminal (`ctrl+~`) resolved my issue.

Comment: This solution worked for me where others didn't.  Some systems like Fedora Linux and Python 3.x support need `pip3 install pylint -U`

Comment: `-U` will upgrade an installed `pylint`, but this doesn't help if VSCode isn't finding `pylint` even though it's installed.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this *if* you're running Visual Studio Code on a Windows machine and getting this error (I'm using Windows 10).

Go to the settings and change the Python path to the location of YOUR python installation.

I.e.,

Change: `"python.pythonPath": "python"`

To: `"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python36\\python.exe"`

And then: *Save* and *reload* Visual Studio Code.

Now when you get the prompt telling you that *"Linter pylint is not installed"*, just select the option to '*install pylint*'.

Since you've now provided the correct path to your Python installation, the Pylint installation will be successfully completed in the Windows PowerShell Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

If you're reading this in (or after) 2020 and are still having issues with Pylint in Visual Studio Code for **Windows 10**, here is a quick solution that worked for me:

Make sure Python is installed for Windows, and note the installation path.

From an elevated command prompt, go to the installation directory for Python:

```
cd C:\Users\[username]\Programs\Python\Python[version]\
```

Install Pylint:

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

Pylint is now installed in the '`Python\Python[version]\Scripts\`' directory, note/copy the path for later.

Open settings in Visual Studio Code: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + ','

Type in `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in the search field, and paste in the path to the Windows installation path for Python:

(e.g. `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python[version]\python.exe`)

Do the same for `python.pythonPath`, using the same path as above.

Lastly, search for `python.linting.pylintpath` and paste the path to pylint.exe.

Restart Visual Studio Code

That got rid of the warnings for me, and successfully enabled pylinting.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Open the cmd and type:

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.  If you also have Visual Studio installed with the Python extension, the system will want to use Studio's version of Python.  Set the Environment Path to the version in Studio's Shared folder.  For me, that was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\
```

After that, run

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

from a command prompt with Administrator rights.

Comment: But the question was about [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), not [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).

Comment: @PeterMortensen The comment was "If you also have Visual Studio installed", meaning "in addition to Code". At the time, Windows would reset VS Code's version of Python to whatever Visual Studio's was. In other words, Visual Studio's setting would override VS Code's. I don't know if that's still true now, three years later, but it was then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), you may need to activate package *pylint* and *autopep8* after you've installed them, i.e.:

```
sudo port select pylint pylint36
sudo port select autopep8 autopep8-36
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well and found the error's log regarding permissions or something.

So, I ran Visual Studio Code with administrator privileges and ran "pip install pylint" in the terminal.
Then the error seemed to be fixed.

(I run Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) then you just have to

```
pipenv install pylint
```

to install Pylint to your virtual environment

```
pipenv shell
```

to activate the environment and thus make Pylint available. Then start `code` in that environment

```
code .
```

**Boom!** you're good to code ;-)

Comment: Yep, also if somebody's wondering why it still complains after `pipenv install pylint`, just reload your workspace in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

The following fix works for me. In a [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) terminal, type:

```
$ pip3 install pylint
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

If your Python 3 is installed in the */usr/bin/python3.6* folder, run the following command, and it should work fine. Last, make sure your Visual Studio Code is running the Python 3 interpreter, not Python 2.7 which is default in Ubuntu.

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install -U pylint
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue happened to me after I a completely reinstalled Python. Opening the `settings.json` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P:</kbd>

and I saw that I had set the default linter  to

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint_django"
```

so opening a terminal (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + ⇧Shift + ~) and the installing

```
pip install pylint_django
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this weekend.  It seems to have happened because I opened my project in my [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/venv.html), but I also opened a second instance outside of the venv.  I never closed either instance - I just shut my PC down and let Windows do the work.  When I went back and called up Visual Studio Code from within my venv, both the project, and the other non-venv window opened.  That's when I started seeing this error.

To fix it, I had to remove the `\.vscode` folder from the workspace directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my trials and my solution following [rob3c's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44833605/982).

PS: My solution only concerns **Windows** users.

### The problem:

I tried the following settings without success:

```
// settings.json
"python.linting.pylintPath": ${workspaceFolder}\\_tools\\python3\\Scripts\\pylint
```

and

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": ${workspaceFolder}\\_tools\\python3\\Scripts\\pylint.exe
```

I always had the following error message:

```
Linter 'pylint' is not installed. Please install it or select another linter".
Error: spawn c:\WS\myproject\_tools\python3\Scripts\pylint ENOENT
```

Even with a `pylint` file in my folder:

```
dir c:\WS\myproject\_tools\python3\Scripts\
...
05.07.2017  09:34 AM                52 pylint    # ! no pylint.exe !
...
```

As my toolchain is based on [MSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#History), the Pylint installed is **without pylint.exe**.

The content of `_tools\python3\Scripts\pylint` file:

```
#!python
from pylint import run_pylint
run_pylint()
```

### The solution

My workaround was to create a batch file **.vscode\pylint.bat** with the following contents:

```
%PYTHON3_EXE% _prefix\python3\Scripts\pylint %*
```

(%PYTHON3_EXE% is an environment variable to the Python 3 interpreter `C:\Python34\python.exe`)

And to configure .vscode\settings.json as follows:

```
// settings.json
"python.linting.pylintPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\pylint.bat",
```

### Result

Log from `OUTPUT` --> `Python`:

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########

c:\WS\myproject> C:\Python34\python.exe _tools\python3\Scripts\pylint
--rcfile c:\WS\framework\pylintrc
--msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{msg_id}:{msg}'
--reports=n
--output-format=text
c:\WS\myproject\myScriptToLint.py
Using config file c:\WS\myproject\pylintrc

------------------------------------

Your code has been rated at 10.00/10
```

✓ *Visual Studio Code* uses the Pylint version from my toolchain!

Comment: It may be effective, but it's a hack. The problem is that VSCode doesn't find pylint even if it's installed and in the `PATH`. I'd rather fix VSCode than work around the problem like this.