# Getting error message "Linter pylint is not installed"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to code some python using vscode on Windows, but for some reason when I try to run it I get the error message "Linter pylint is not installed". It also says "The terminal process command 'C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe' failed to launch.

I saw this thread [Linter pylint is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272664/linter-pylint-is-not-installed) , and have tried to do the top answers to no avail. I don't know where to type some of the instructions (I have tried both the command prompt and cygwin terminal on Windows). This just gives me nonsense about "no pylint in _____", which is long address.

Literally just using this code:

```py
print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Pylint w/ `"python.linting.enabled": false` or explicitly Pylint with `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false`.

But if you want Pylint then the issue is cygwin isn't working as your shell in order to run Pylint. As well, the Python extension does not support cygwin and so there's no specific way to suggest help on how to fix it.