# Im an Absolutely Beginner Python Coder

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

i was installing python 3.8.2 + visual studio code. when im done with step to installing python extension.
but when im try to code some `print ('hello world')` things the linter pylint always showed up? and i got syntax error like this

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file c:\Users\Dell on line 1
```

what shouold i do, master?

[image: linter pylint is not installed]

[when i click install button on linter pylint popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeIsK.png)

Comment: According to the screenshot, the program works correctly. There are no syntax errors shown. Please clarify your question.

Comment: What happened when you clicked that `Install` button?

Comment: Obviously, the cause of the error is a space in the path. I think this is not your problem, because the command can be executed correctly after adding the quotation marks. I think you can go to the github page of python-extension  to submit an issue

Comment: Never use spaces in any file or directory name

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ..." or "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with ..." trying to use non-ASCII text in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-or-syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting)

Answer (score 0):

you can install pylint to help catch bugs in your code. You can find out how to do so here:[Linter pylint is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272664/linter-pylint-is-not-installed?rq=1)

As for the syntax error, its likely to be caused by additional characters added to the code because the text was copied from a word processor, you can rewrite the code to fix the issue. You can find out more about the issue here: [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x91'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092176/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x91)

In the future it might be helpful to search the error code on the internet first before posting a question. e.g. searching "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with" on Google to get answers more quickly since its likely someone else has answered the same question already. Good luck! :>