# Why does my conda environment work on one VSCode window but NOT on the others?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, conda

I got an annoying issue triggered my obsession.

I am using vscode on Mac. I have a python conda env and I am normally using it.

For one vscode window, when I do the log check through 'Output' button, it looks good:

```
Experiment 'pythonaa' is active
Experiment 'pythonTensorboardExperiment' is active
Experiment 'pythonSurveyNotification' is active
Experiment 'PythonPyTorchProfiler' is active
Experiment 'pythonDeprecatePythonPath' is active
> conda info --json
> ~/anaconda3/envs/gnn/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py
> ~/anaconda3/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py
> ~/anaconda3/envs/crawler/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py
Python interpreter path: ~/anaconda3/envs/gnn/bin/python
> . ~/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate gnn && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
Starting Pylance language server.
> ~/anaconda3/envs/gnn/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/pythonFiles/linter.py -m pylint ./greedy.py
cwd: .
```

but when I opened the other windows, I got

```
ERROR 2022-1-6 15:57:27.538]: getActivatedEnvironmentVariables [SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //[mypath]: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at h ([mypath]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/out/client/extension.js:104:312461)
    at d.getDisplayCommands ([mypath]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/out/client/extension.js:104:312240)
    at d.logProcess ([mypath]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/out/client/extension.js:104:311978)
    at s.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at shellExec ([mypath]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/out/client/extension.js:52:33373)
    at P.getActivatedEnvironmentVariablesImpl ([mypath]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1786462952/out/client/extension.js:85:118653)]
Starting Pylance language server.

Linter 'pylint' is not installed. Please install it or select another linter".
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //[mypath]: Nothing to repeat
```

I use [mypath] to alternate my local path.

Please enlighten me how to solve it. I am sure my conda env is rightly linked to my vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Error message "Linter pylint is not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272664/error-message-linter-pylint-is-not-installed)

You need to activate the `conda` environment manually on the second one if not triggered automatically.

Check this `conda` guide to get more clarity on such environments: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: When I open my VScode, the env is automatically activated. It just failed for some reason.

Comment: Did you try installing `pylint` to both your base and new enviroment: `conda install pylint`

Comment: I don't think the issue is on my pylint, because I got one window working normally, I chose the same interpreter, same settings, same working&user env.

Comment: But the conda on this window, just doesn't normally triggered.

Comment: It seems you are facing a similar issue as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272664/error-message-linter-pylint-is-not-installed

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. But I think the issue is on getActivatedEnvironmentVariables [SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //[mypath]: Nothing to repeat

Comment: There are //, this double slash seems like Windows path style.

Comment: My setting.json can not even work. I change "python.linting.pylintPath": to my path, but it also doesn;t work, same log.

Comment: Did you determine your path to `pylint` using `which pylint`? Also please update the same in settings and restart your VS code applicaiton.

Comment: sure, that's what Ive done

Comment: Try the other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272664/error-message-linter-pylint-is-not-installed hope that helps